# Can't log into websites

Tags: blocked-services

I cannot log into websites.  Screen just refreshes and wipes out my login information.  Is there a way around this . . . a plugin or something?

P.S.  I saw the other posts, but there weren't any answers.

Thanks

Comment: Which website is affected?